# Firebase / AngularFire limited object deletes its properties on $save()

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I have a primary node in my database called 'questions', when I create a ref to that node and bring it into my project as a $asObject(), I can modify the individual questions and $save() the collection without any problems, however as soon as I try to limit the object, by priority, the $save() deletes everything off of the object!

this works fine:

```
db.questions = $firebase(fb.questions).$asObject(); 
// later :
db.questions.$save();
// db.questions is an object with many 'questions', which I can edit and resave as I please
```

but as soon as I switch my code to this:

```
db.questions = $firebase(fb.questions.startAt(auth.user.id).endAt(auth.user.id)).$asObject();
// later :
db.questions.$save();
// db.questions is an empty firebase object without any 'questions!'
```

Is there some limitation to limited objects (pun not intended) and their ability to be changed and saved?? The saving actually saves updates to the questions to the database, but somehow nukes the local $firebase object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First line of synchronized arrays (`$asArray`) documentation:

> Synchronized arrays should be used for any list of objects that will be sorted, iterated, and which have unique ids.

First line of synchronized objects (`$asObject`) documentation:

> Objects are useful for storing key/value pairs, and singular records that are not used as a collection.

As demonstrated, if you are going to work with a collection and employ `limit`, it would behoove you to use a tool designed for collections (i.e. $asArray).

If you were to recreate the behavior of `$save` using the Firebase SDK, it would look like this:

```
var ref = new Firebase(URL).limit(10);
// ref.set(data); // throws an error!
ref.ref().set(data); // replaces the entire path; same as $save
```

Thus, the behavior here exactly matches the SDK. You cannot, technically, call set() on a query instance and this doesn't make any sense, really. What does limit(10) mean to a JSON object? If you call set, which 10 unordered keys should be set? There is no correlation here and limit() really only makes sense with a collection of data, not a list of key/value pairs.

Hope that helps.